# Can an Android app upgrade itself?

Tags: android, system

Is it possible to update application from itself in Android? The app in question is a system app, so I can execute privileged commands. Also note that I don't want to show any notification to user, so everything should work in the background.

Comment: of course you can... you can try polling in specific intervals. OR you can use C2DM (Cloud to Device Messaging). C2DM is specifically for this purpose.

Comment: suppose I have the file in sdcard. I am interested in updating part not downloading part.

Comment: you'd need to use a root shell command that will enable r/w, copy the apk file to /system/app/. and then switch back to r/o.

Comment: @Tim is that possible from an Android application?

Comment: @you786 It is technically possible to do from an application yes. But the device it is running on must be rooted. And since most (all) rooted devices have the SuperUser.apk installed the user is still going be notified that you application is attempting to use a super user command, and will still have the option to disallow it from happening.

Comment: Hmm, is that still true if the app is installed in system/app? Also, can you point me in a direction that shows how to run these kind of commands?

Answer (score 2):

It is actually pretty easy for an app to update itself, the hard part is doing it without putting up a prompt to the user.  The app needs to download the APK, then send it to the *PackageManager* API to install it.  Android will then put up the install prompt.  There is a library to handle that part:

- https://gitlab.com/fdroid/update-channels

As for doing it with prompting, the app needs privileged access.  If the device is rooted, the app can request root access.  The app can also be flashed as a "priv-app" so that it has privileged access.  Or you can do it like F-Droid: flash the [Privileged Extension](https://gitlab.com/fdroid/privileged-extension) as a "priv-app", and make your app send install/uninstall requests to Privileged Extension.

Otherwise, you need to download binary code, and dynamically load it, like @yusuf-x said.  Be aware that Google is working to make that impossible in each new release of Android.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java ClassLoader to dynamically load code that was push or pulled down. – Yusuf X just now edit. I've used this for just such a purpose on Android.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Fdroid is an open source application repository.
Their client app can install/update/delete apps from the fdroid repository, including itself.

See the code for the installer part of the client app here:
https://gitlab.com/fdroid/fdroidclient/tree/master/app/src/main/java/org/fdroid/fdroid/installer